# Surviving Enter/carriage return in C

Tags: c, newline, scanf

```
# make test
cc     test.c   -o test
# ./test
I am a happy yam until i hit return...
# ./test
because it ends my [BLEEPING] program....
# ./test
OOOH  how my blood doth burn !!!  ...doth? ...doest? ...meh...
# cat test.c
#include "usual_suspects.h"

int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf( "%d", &i);
}
# echo 'So, how do I continue onto the next line
> without terminating the program? Not a wrapping function but,surviving
> hitting the enter key?
```

Not quite the Dornishman's wife but hey, I'm low budget and half-brained. xD
is scanf the write way (see what i did there) to go with this?

**UPDATE- as per answer a la hexturtle**

```
# make test
cc     test.c   -o test
# ./test
Well blow me down, a cross-eyed clown !
Said a can of yams imported from Spain.
If i had a bucket to spit,       
I'd sorely say frak-it and quit !
Whilst watching my brine wash away
        with the rain. xD
^C
# YES !!!!!!!!!
bash: YES: command not found
# cat test.c
#include "usual_suspects.h"

int main()
{
    int i;
    while (true) {
        scanf("&d", &i);
    }
}
```

**Final edit, promise =D**
OKAY, This is as small as it get's i think.

```
#include "usual_suspects.h"
    int main()
    {
        while (true) {         
        scanf("%d");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many lines do you want to read?

Comment: In my experience, C's `scan` functions are never the right solution. I always just `fgets()` a big string and do the interpretation myself.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , thank you for your reply. All of them, what's preventing me from moving on to figuring out hotkey combos work in C IS this issue. I want the program to keep going line after enter key  after line and so on, of input until i issue a key-combo to bring up a save, exit, etc. dialog. I am a beginner.

Comment: If you want to work with lines like that; take a look at [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) or [editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/). And, for key-combos (and terminal manipulation) I'd suggest [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and/or [`termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , Thanks again, I am looking at ncurses but still a bit dense, i almost have a handle on colors though. I tried the recursive trick with the above which was goofy and fun but ultimately meh.

Comment: You changed `%d` to `&d`. Oops!

Comment: @Kaz yeah but it still seemed to work. Is that odd? I though & would return address?

Comment: @Kaz both `%d` and `&d` work. =p i am confuzed.

Comment: The first argument you pass to `scanf()` is a format string. A format string is used in many functions such as `scanf()` and `printf()`. I suggest doing some reading on format strings for better understanding how they work. That said, `%d` serves as a format specifier for the format string which makes it "special" when found within a format string. `&d` on the other hand is just plain text in the context of a format string. Note that `&`, in the context of a format string or any other string, is just a character and does not function like the address-of operator.

Comment: The fact that there is no observable difference between your use of `%d` and `&d` in the format string is to be expected since you don't seem to be doing anything with the variable `i`. Again, I suggest looking into how format strings work in order to understand why this is the case. But in the context of your example, it makes sense, and would be expected, for you to be using `%d` (or a similar format specifier) rather than `&d` which doesn't really make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `scanf()` the program will block, waiting for console input. Thus, once you press enter, the input you submitted will be read in and `scanf()` will return. Once `scanf()` returns, your program will continue to execute. In the example you gave, there is no more code to execute after `scanf()` returns. Therefore, the `main()` function implicitly returns 0 and causes your program to exit.

If you want to continue reading in lines of input, you can do something like the following:

```
while (true) {
    scanf("%d", &i);
}
```

In practice, there are better ways to do this, as Elliot Frisch mentioned. But in principle, this is what I think you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `fread()` function does what you say you want.  It will read a specified number of bytes or until it reaches an EOF, which is inputted to the keyboard with a CTRL+D on unix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 500

int main()
{
    // Declare a char array to read into
    char str[MAX_STR_LEN + 1];

    // Read into the char array until MAX_STR_LEN bytes
    // have been read or EOF
    fread(str, 1, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);

    // Null Terminate and print what we read in
    str[MAX_STR_LEN] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

This downside is you don't get the fancy `scanf` format specifiers.  You just have to deal with the big resultant string yourself.

But realize this: in the background, `fread()` is making multiple `read()` system calls, which return after each newline.  So I don't think there is anything to be gained from a single function that survives newlines.

In practice, what I've found the best solution to "read past newlines" is to read a file line-by-line.  That can be done with the more elegant code below, and if you really need the resulting strings concatenated, just use `strcat()` on the strings as they come.

```
while (EOF != scanf("%s", &str)) {
   // Do something
}
```

But the code above does what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for this as well, I would green check but hexturtle won out.

Comment: `fgets` is vastly superior to `scanf("%s"` if all you want to do is read input line by line. Using `scanf` for that is the hard, slow, inefficient way to do it.